# jquery bookshelf Slider modifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, onload

I am creating book shelf using **jquery bookshelf Slider**. Its Working good but i need some modifications in my book self.

Our Book self demo link
[Book shelf demo](http://www.almmag.com/issues/test-bookshelf-slider/)

Our modifications are given below :

- Default load time **title and icons** are hide.
- if we need to click  title or icons. show the title or icon.

Our Script is given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">



jQuery(document).ready(function() {



    //define custom parameters

    $.bookshelfSlider('#bookshelf_slider', {

        'item_width': '100%', //responsive design > resize window to see working

        'item_height': 320,

        'products_box_margin_left': 30,

        'product_title_textcolor': '#ffffff',

        'product_title_bgcolor': '#c33b4e',

        'product_margin': 20,

        'product_show_title': true,

        'show_title_in_popup': true,

        'show_selected_title': true,

        'show_icons': true,

        'buttons_margin': 15,

        'buttons_align': 'center', // left, center, right

        'slide_duration': 800,

        'slide_easing': 'easeOutQuart',

        'arrow_duration': 800,

        'arrow_easing': 'easeInOutQuart',

        'video_width_height': [500,290],

        'iframe_width_height': [500,330]

        }

    );



});//ready



</script>
```

We are already try to change the `'product_show_title': true,` to

```
'product_show_title': false,
```

But its not working for me. so please advise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the opacity of the title and icons properly after plugin initialization.

```
    //define custom parameters
    $.bookshelfSlider('#bookshelf_slider', {
        'item_width': 605,
        'item_height': 720,
        'products_box_margin_left': 30,
        'product_title_textcolor': '#ffffff',
        'product_title_bgcolor': '#c33b4e',
        'product_margin': 30,
        'product_show_title': true,
        'show_title_in_popup': true,
        'show_selected_title': true,
        'show_icons': true,
        'buttons_margin': 15,
        'buttons_align': 'center', // left, center, right
        'slide_duration': 800,
        'slide_easing': 'easeInOutExpo',
        'arrow_duration': 800,
        'arrow_easing': 'easeInOutExpo',
        'video_width_height': [600,600],
        'iframe_width_height': [600,600]
        }
    );

$(".show_hide_titles, .show_hide_icons").css('opacity','0.5');
$(".product_title, .icons_sprite").css('opacity','0');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/A8s4f/)**

Comment: Hi @Mahesh Sapkal i need another help from you please help. I would like to add link to my bookshelfSlider popup.How can i add like for the popup image